# Center element to middle of the page horizontally CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know how I can center an element to the middle of the page horizontally.

Here is my code:

```
#item {
    height:400px;
    width:700px;
    background-color:white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

I'd like to center this so it looks like that:

[image: example]

(Centered  horizontally and a few pixels below the header)

Thanks, M4DNE55

Comment: `text-align: center; margin: 0 auto`?

Comment: (a) is there anything else in that header?, (b) is the header fixed height, or dynamic?, (c) do u support IE8 and below? as others have said, horizontal is easy, but vertical is not ... doable, depending on those questions

Answer (score 1):

Just add these

`text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
display:table-cell;`

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal is easy, it's vertical that's a bother.
To centre in-line elements such as text and images, use `text-align:center;`.

To centre divs you can use `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

To center something in general, use

```
margin:0px auto;
```

this is equivalent to

```
margin-top:0px
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:0px
margin-left:auto;
```

or

```
margin 0px auto 0px auto;
```

you should go for something like:

```
margin 30px auto 0px auto;
```

note that this only works with elements that have a set width.
Also, you could use

```
    line-height: 'your div height'
```

to align the text in the middle

Answer (score 0):

`{width : auto; margin : auto}` will work, you may need to fix the width of the element you to center

Comment: Thank you, but now I get this: http://prntscr.com/5h47ke
And I can't add a margin-top:..px;

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following to your CSS code:

```
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 400px; /* the same as your div height */
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/95fhsw8z/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute position, to center it on the page

```
#item {
    height:400px;
    width:700px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    margin-left: -350px;
    background-color:white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a div outside of this div and make its width 100%. Now give your `div margin: 0 aut`o; with a `position: relative`. This should work.

```
<div style="width:100%">
  <div id="item"></div>
</div>
```